# "Cannot read property '_blazorFilesById' of null error" with Blazor InputFile component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazorinputfile

I've started getting this error from my Blazor WebAssembly app:

> "Cannot read property '_blazorFilesById' of null error" with Blazor app

I'm assuming that's related to the `InputFile` [component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#inputfile-component) I'm using, which has been working fine.

I've tried restarting VS, clean & rebuilding, restarting IIS and killing Chrome all to no avail.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This turns out to be because I'd added conditional code to hide the `InputFile` component on the page.  Doing that will cause the error as explained in [this post on GitHub by BtbN](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile/issues/41#issuecomment-692756392):

> Did you modify your page, so the InputFile element is not rendered
> anymore? It has to stay present, otherwise the browser cleans up any
> resources associated with it.

Comment: Good tip. I had my file input control on modal window. Inside the modal window a thread was fired off to process the file, but the modal window closed quickly, before the thread had completed, and got the same error.

Comment: A great solution. I was stack for several hours for that

Comment: This worked for me. I had my form wrapped in a if (_isLoading) {} and that caused this.

Answer (score 4):

I tried keeping the InputFile component inside a Div and conditionally (based on a bool @uploadingInProgress) hiding the Div (esp. during the upload progress) works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

this is happening because you are most likely calling StatehasChanged in the onchange function